# VMware Workstation black screen while starting virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have VMware Workstation 15.0.2 , in the past i had no problem with it but recently , **sometimes when i want to start a machine it freezes on a black screen**, and when it happens i can't even suspend it , i try to end the task but it doesnt work

I tried already this command : `taskkill /pid vmware-vmx.exe_pid`

But i get access denied error because the instance could not be found ( ***even if im using administrator cmd*** )

Does anyone knows the cause of this error or how to solve it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Download VMware Workstation 15.5.5 (free upgrade for you). Uninstall the current version, restart, and install the new version.  Test the new version.

Comment: Thanks i will try that @John

Comment: @KaramMohamed Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue with Workstation 16.1.2 and a Win 10 VM.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Yes i did it by updating Vmware Workstation , i deleted it completely and downloaded the newer vesion